# RowUpdating Event of Gridview is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I wanted to update my table through gridview. [Visual Studio 2010]

For that i have done following:

Gridview>> EditColumns >> CommandField >> Edit,update,cancel Added to grid.

Gridview>> EditTemplates >> Added textbox names "`TextBox1`">>End Editing Template.

**Row Editing Event:**

```
public int i;
protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   i=gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}
```

**Row Updating Event:**

```
protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                TextBox txtSymbol;

                txtSymbol = ((TextBox)(gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1")));

                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update temp set Symbol=@Symbol", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@Symbol",txtSymbol.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

I refered this code from [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/147556-Asp.net-Gridview-row-editing.aspx).

Here its mentioned that th line should be like this:

**txtSymbol = ((TextBox)(gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1")));**

All this coded thing is not working.

```
`((TextBox)(gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1")))`
```

is having null value.

Gives exception in Row Updating event as **"Null Referance Exception."**

What is wrong in my code?

Where i am making mistake.

Please guid me.

Comment: you have to bind gridview again on both evet i.e. Edit and Update

Comment: but without binding, effect should be there on DB. But its not showing effect. And as i said, its giving me exception

Comment: Also your update command will update EVERY row in table.

Comment: @gzaxx but i have set only 1 field for updation.

Comment: i know its not an answer to what you are asking, but for the next time it would be a lot more easier to use the entity framework and bind it to the grid... the update methods would commit automatically...

Comment: @MatanL okey, Thanx for suggetion

Comment: if you dont bind gridview again on editing than your update event is not called

Comment: try this
 txtSymbol = ((TextBox)(gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1")));
and check i think you will solve your "Null Reference error" and you can  go further in your updation process.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
   BindGridView();//You have  to  Bind GridView Again Here...
}
```

If you dont bind the Gridview Again After setiing it Edit Index your control is not bounded With gridview.Thats why it giving you null refrence exception.